Как сделать, чтобы информация из одной Activity передавалась в lIstView в другой Activity?
Я только учусь Kotlin и впринципе пользоваться Android Studio. Сегодня долго бился над задачей, нужно из MeinActivity2 передать строчку в listView в MeinActivity. Четкого ответа на этот вопрос в интернете я не нашел, а образрые намеки мне трудно понятны по причине малых знаний. Обьясните как это сделать
MainActivity

import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.EditText
import android.widget.ListView
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.activity.enableEdgeToEdge
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var todos: MutableList<String>  // Поле класса для списка
    private lateinit var adapter: ArrayAdapter<String> // Поле класса для адаптера

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        enableEdgeToEdge()
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val listView = findViewById<ListView>(R.id.listView)
        val button: Button = findViewById(R.id.Button)

        val todos: MutableList<String> = mutableListOf()
        val adapter = ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, todos)
        listView.adapter = adapter

        button.setOnClickListener() {
            val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity2::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
        }
    }
    


}

MainActivity2

import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.EditText
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.activity.enableEdgeToEdge
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity

class MainActivity2 : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        enableEdgeToEdge()
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2)

        val backButton: Button = findViewById(R.id.button23)
        val sendButton: Button = findViewById(R.id.button)
        val sendText: EditText = findViewById(R.id.editText)


        backButton.setOnClickListener {
            finish()
        }
    }
}


Для передачи данных между активити используется intent: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/parcelables-and-bundles#sdba
